# How to make a promise to check if a function is called after some time with Sinon.js

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, ecmascript-6, sinon, jestjs

I am writing tests for React.js app with Jest and Enzyme.
I use [Sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/) to make spies of the member functions of React components.
One of the issues is how to test if the component is redirecting successfully with REST API calls.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  ...
  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
     ...
     if (this.props.phase === 'LOADING' && props.phase === 'SUCCESS') {
        // redirect codes here
     }
  }
  handleClickMyButton() {
    dispatch(action)
  }
```

My approach is

```
it ('Should be redirected', async () => {
  const spyPromise = ? // spy promise to componentWillReceiveProps will be called with certain parameters.
  const myComponentWrapper = wrapper.find(MyComponent)
  // simulate click event codes here

  const result = await spyPromise
  // check if it is redirected via history object

})
```

But I am not sure how to make `spyPromise` here.

Comment: Maybe you need to add a bit more code to explain what and why you want to test here. I would also not spy on internal methods of React components but on the code that make the redirect. So if you change the `document.location.href` just check that it was set using `expect(global.document.location.href).toBe('')`. Also it is not necessary to use sinon as jest has most of the features build in.

Comment: I have no problem with `this.context.router.tansitionTo` but I am not sure how to make `spyPromise` to make it wait until the REST api call is completed.

Comment: From your example it is not clear where `spyPromise` is used

Comment: `const result = await spyPromise` I am waiting until the REST api call is completed. `spy promise to componentWillReceiveProps will be called with certain parameters.`

Comment: This is not how it works. Normally you would mock the REST call with a resolved promise and use this with `await`. Your component should be designed, so it is possible to either pass the promise into your component or you can mock the module that is used to make the call. Just creating a promise outside that is not interacting with your module will have no effect.

Comment: So it would help if you would post the code that leads to `componentWillReceiveProps` call

Comment: I have already mocked all REST APIs but I just want to have a test of the whole component logic + redux

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138192/discussion-between-andreas-koberle-and-colin-witkamp).